# SQL queries with AND/OR conditions

Tags: 8, database

I'm transferring SQL statements from a Drupal 5 installation to Drupal 8, and struggling with And/Or condtions. eg given the original SQL:

```
    SELECT .....
    WHERE .....
          AND classes.description = "Photographer"
          AND (classoptions.description = "Name of photographer here"
           OR classoptions.description = "Not assigned").
```

I've translated it to:

```
$query = $this->dbConnection->select('classes');
....etc....
$query->condition('classes.description', 'Photographer');
```

So far, so good. Then I need an OR condition for

```
$query->condition('classoptions.description', 'Name of photographer here');
$query->condition('classoptions.description', 'Not assigned');
```

Looking at documentation on-line, using db_or() is suggested, as in :

```
$query->condition(db_or()
 ->condition('classoptions.description', 'Name of photographer here');
 ->condition('classoptions.description', 'Not assigned'));
```

..but this is a) deprecated, b) gives error 'db_or function not found'
The replacement for db_or() is to obtain a new Condition object, but what am I supposed to do with it?  The function

```
 $query->orConditionGroup();
```

Will return a new Condition object, and the code

```
$query->condition(orConditionGroup()
 ->condition('classoptions.description', 'Name of photographer here');
 ->condition('classoptions.description', 'Not assigned'));
```

Formats a Condition object with the conditions to be ORed just fine.But again, how do I incorporate this into the query?

Answer (score 13):

Have a look how `orConditionGroup()` is used in core.
For example, in `ConfigEntityQueryTest` it is used this way:

```
$query = $this->factory->get('config_query_test', 'AND');
$and_condition_1 = $query->orConditionGroup()
  ->condition('id', '2')
  ->condition('label', $this->entities[0]->label);
$and_condition_2 = $query->orConditionGroup()
  ->condition('id', 1)
  ->condition('label', $this->entities[3]->label);
$this->queryResults = $query
  ->condition($and_condition_1)
  ->condition($and_condition_2)
  ->execute();
```

I am sure you can apply this to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. That works ( I thought I'd already tried that!) I ended up coding   
$query->condition('classes.description','Photographer');
$query->condition($query->orConditionGroup()
->condition('classoptions.description', $photographer)
->condition('classoptions.description', 'Not assigned'));   You can also use ->where('sql snippet', args) to perform the SQL conditions in full, although this seem to go against the grain of most D8 SQL methods.

Answer (score 10):

For the sake of completeness, this worked for me (thanks to the original poster):

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
  ->condition('vid', 'surface');
$group = $query->orConditionGroup()
  ->condition('field_surface_exclude', NULL, 'IS NULL')
  ->condition('field_surface_exclude', 0);
$tids = $query->condition($group)->execute();
```